# Simple Maths Question - Capital Sigma/Pi

Tags: recurrence-relations

I haven't studied math in  a long time and am trying to solve a simple first order non-homogeneous recurrence relation. This approach uses the general formula:

$$  f(n) = \prod_{i=a+1}^n b(i) \bigg\{ f(a) + \sum_{j = a+1}^nd(j)\bigg\}. $$

The recurrence relation itself is

$$  f(n) = 6f(n-1) -5;  (n > 0)$$

Therefore, $b(i) = 6, f(a) = 2, a = 0, d(j) = -5/6.$

I am a little rusty with maths so am not too confident of the ordering of the calculations.

My attempt:

Calculate

$$\sum_{j = a+1}^nd(j)$$

So $(n - (a+1) + 1) . d(j) = -5/6n$.
Add $f(a)$ to get $2 - 5/6n$. 
Now sub into general equation:
 
$\prod_1^n 6(2 - 5/6n)$.  I'm not sure how to do this...

The next part is where I am unsure - I'm not entirely sure what the brackets mean after $b(i)$. Could someone help me work through this...I HAVE to use the above formula...

Here is the screenshot from my notes:

[image]

Comment: You can simply enclose LaTeX in `$`-signs, so `$\prod_{i =1, i \ne j}^{n} t_i$` produces $\prod_{i =1, i \ne j}^{n} t_i$. You obtain displayed formulae by enclosing them in double dollar signs `$$...$$`. As is, I find your question a bit hard to parse.

Comment: @user9492 Please re-type your question out, so at least we can help you with the problem with whatever methods we know e.g. generating functions, hypergeometric functions, etc.

Comment: @user9492 I have attempted to edit your question correctly.  Please review the edit to see if it is still what you want to say.  I do not really understand what the question is.

Comment: @Glen: Thanks, unfortunately user9492 edited at the same time as you. @user9492: Please look at the source code how Glen did it.

Comment: @Glen & Theo - thanks. I have no clue how to write this mathjax stuff - sorry guys. All the editing is correct except there should be some {} surrounding 'f(a)....d(j)' in the general forumla...

Comment: Is this okay now?

Comment: Thats is exactly how the problem reads, thanks for the edits...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if I understand correctly, you want to find an explicit expression for the recursively defined function $f$ given by
$$f(n) = \begin{cases} 6 f(n-1) - 5\, & \text{if } n \gt 0, \\2 & \text{if } n = 0.\end{cases}$$

In order to get a feel for this function $f$, let me calculate some values
\begin{align*}
  f(0) & = 2 \\
  f(1) & = 6 f(0) - 5 = 6 \cdot 2 - 5 = 7 \\
  f(2) & = 6 f(1) - 5 = 6 \cdot 7 - 5 = 37 \\
  f(3) & = 6 f(2) - 5 = 6 \cdot 37 - 5 = 217 \\
  f(4) & = 6 f(3) - 5 = 6 \cdot 217 - 5 = 1297 \\
       & \vdots
\end{align*}
Well, you might already see the pattern here, at least the numbers $f(n) - 1 = 1,6, 36, 216$ for $n = 1,2,3$ could look familiar..., namely $1 = 6^0$, $6 = 6^1$, $36 = 6^2$ and $216 = 6^3$. Finally, $1296 = 6^4$, so we can cut a long story short by saying that
$f(n) -1 = 6^n$ or
$$f(n) = 6^n + 1.$$

We can now go and prove this formula by induction. For $n=0$ our formula gives $f(0) = 6^0 + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2$, so that's ok.
*Now assume* that $f(n-1) = 6^{n-1} + 1$ holds for some $n \gt 0$. We want to show that then $f(n) = 6^n + 1$ follows from the recursion. But if $f(n-1) = 6^{n-1} + 1$ then the recursion gives
$$f(n) = 6f(n-1) - 5 = 6 (6^{n-1} + 1) - 5 = 6 \cdot 6^{n-1} + (6 - 5) = 6^{n} + 1,$$
as we wanted.

Well, this might seem as a bit of magic I pulled out of the hat here, but I don't think the general formula is of any help here.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for your reply. Yes that is the exact problem. Unfortunately this question is for an exam and we must use the equation above to find the solution - Sorry!

Comment: @user9492: I must admit that I don't understand the formula you give. What does $d(j)$ mean?

Comment: d(j) is merely the result of taking the constant (-5) and dividing it by the coefficient of f(n-1) -> (6), which yields -5/6.

Comment: Maybe its a mistake in my lecture notes? I've included a screenshot of the original formula from my notes.

Comment: @user9492: No I don't think it's a mistake, it was mine, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

The general procedure for your recurrences is given [here](http://www.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Gorse/teaching/gc05/gc05_2.pdf).  This link goes into great depth on the method you're learning about.

Also, the formula above can be found on page 27.  This should help make everything more clear.

There's also a formula you can use to check to ensure that you have the correct answer.  For a recurrence

$u_{n+1}=a\cdot u_n + b$

The solution for $u_n$ is given by the formula

$u_n = \left(u_0 + \frac{b}{a-1}\right) a^n + \frac{b}{a-1}$